# How can I Embed my password with script

Tags: windows-xp, script, runas

I have a requirement that I must run a script(with administratiev priviledge) during one of my  Guest user startup.But I dont want to prompt my user for any password.In my case I'm ok with  leaving my password insecure embedding it with my script .Can I achieve this using 'RunAs' or any other tool like that?

Comment: Use a scheduled task on the user logon but put your admin user in the area where who the task is run as.

Comment: Hi Chris! Can you elaborate a bit more!

Comment: Have a read of this page and tailor it to your needs: http://m.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-task-in-windows-xp-scheduled-tasks.html

Comment: Hi Chris! Can I configure it for not running during admin user login and run only for my Guest user?

Comment: Having not used XP for a number of years I've forgotten the settings. I don't know about the Guest user or whether you can create scheduled tasks for it. You can try. Log in as the user and create a task. You can then use your admin credentials for the task it runs.